# how to store webtable in java collection hashmap or hashset or arraylist?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In my application on users profile page, user has:

```
Name: XYZ
Age: ##
Address: st.XYZ
```

and so on...

When an element is missing (example age) other row takes its place, so I can't hardcode the `xpath` of elements. What I want is:

I want to (print) extract entire table data and compare with actual.
So when I ask for "Name" as key it should give cell value infront of it as value of key.

What I tried:
I was able to get text of `tr` tags elements keeping `td` fixed. But for another user when some row is missing it fails or gives wrong value.

```
for (int i = 2; i < 58; i++) {
    String actor_name = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions
            .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(first_part+i+part_two))).getText();
    System.out.print("\n"+"S.no. "+(i-1)+" "+actor_name);
    try {


        driver.findElement(By.xpath(first_part+i+part_two)).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("bio"))).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("bio")).click();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Not a link");
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    System.out.print(" "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='overviewTable']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText());
    driver.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2310332/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast");
}
```

Above code works fine for top 3 actors on [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2310332/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) page but fails for 4th because that doesn't have one row missing on bio page.

On the bio page there two columns in the table one has attribute other has its value. I want to make a collection with key value pair with `key` as attribute (value from left column) and its `value` as value from right column. So that I get the freedom of fetching the values by mentioning the attribute value.

I am using JAVA to write scripts.

Comment: Could you post an HTML representation of the table? Thanks.

Comment: check **overview** section [here](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000093/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm)

Comment: Do not link to anything off-site. Include the relevant pieces of HTML here, by editing the question. Likewise, show the code you have so far, that is failing in some cases.

Comment: While u are searching for a row, put that in try-catch so that if row is not visible for that tag, you can assign null value or blank in the value of that key.

Comment: @VivekSingh I also working on this and have idea on it. I dont this is optimum way or even feasible in java. What I am thinking is in my collections(not sure it would be arraylist or set or map)`key` would be `driver.findElement(By.xpath(//tr/td[text()="Height"]))` and its pair `value` would be `driver.findElement(By.xpath(//tr/td[text()="Height"]/td[1])).getText()`. I'll put this code block in try catch if "Height" found get its value otherwise print height of actor not mentioned.

Comment: Sorry in above code `value` would have xpath like this `//tr/td[text()="Height"]/following-sibling::td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try out with following code and provide me with any concerns if you have any...

```
driver.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2310332/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast");
String height = "";
String actorName = "";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> lstUrls = driver.findElements(By
    .xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']/..")); // all a tags
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
for (WebElement webElement : lstUrls) {
    urls.add(webElement.getAttribute("href")); // saving all hrefs attached in each a tag
}
Map<String, String> actorHeightData = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String string : urls) {
    driver.get(string);
    actorName = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath(".//*[@id='overview-top']/h1/span")).getText(); // Getting actor's name
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Biography']")).click(); // Clicking Biography
    try {
        height = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//td[.='Height']/following-sibling::td"))
                .getText(); // Getting height
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        height = ""; // If height not found
    }
    actorHeightData.put(actorName, height); // Adding to map
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked with minor tweaks, but no doubt your code is faster than mine.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create class PersonData with all nullable fields you need. But with not null getters.

for example

```
calss PersonData{
private String name;

public getName(){
if(name == null)
return "";
return name;
}
}
```

and store all persons in a List.

In you page you will ask person for field and always have something in table's cell.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didnt get what you're saying.Let me explain what I'm trying to do.[Here](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000093/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) I want the height of the person which is stored in `tr` tag.What I want is first identify the `tag` of Height and then get corresponding cell value which is infront of it.Using this,if, for actors Height data is missing it wont fail or give some other value,it'll simply say height data isn't available.Hint to my problem could be a collection which also stores `object` as `key`. I know "what" but dont know "how" to implement,me being a java beginner.

Comment: So, each of your actors has set of tags with values. Set of tags can be different for different actors. You need to iterate through tags and for each tag get value. Your question is how to store tags, values and how to iterate. Right?

Comment: This is just an example, imagine their is table of which has so many user names in one column and each user has corresponding delete button. How you would make sure that you would click correct delete button. So for that you have to find out user name and then click its delete button. What I would do I will store username as key and call corresponding delete button using key.